# Bootstrap-Table - 'data-search' delete box-shadow

Tags: css, search, bootstrap-5, bootstrap-table

Can anyone tell me how I can remove the box-shadow from the search box when I click on it?

Although I know how to remove the box-shadow from a class, in CSS, I don't know how to remove the box-shadow from a property of the  tag, such as "data-search".

Answer (score 0):

The input field created by using the data-search option has a two classes: `form-control` (which inherits the bootstrap styling and thus the box-shadow for a focused input) and `search-input`, which is likely somewhat unique to bootstrap-table so that can be used to override the default behavior.

Note: Do check that nothing else in your page has this class for which you wouldn't want to override the default behavior.

The CSS for this, and there may be another way with SASS but for the sake of this example I think CSS is the easiest and most understandable way, the following could be used.

```
    .search-input:focus {
      box-shadow: none;
      border: 1px solid #ced4da;
    }
```

`.search-input:focus` will only apply the CSS when focused.

`box-shadow: none;` will remove the box shadow.

However, the field will still be outlined blue, just without the shadow. If that's desired, then skip the next line.

If you want the box to look exactly the same regardless of focus, then it can be set to mimic its unfocused styling with
`border: 1px solid #ced4da;` assuming the default color scheme hasn't been changed.

[A working example can be found here, on the bootstrap-table online editor.](https://live.bootstrap-table.com/code/nickjrotundo/15515)